# How to implement control of the aircraft by the camera?

Tags: ros

To begin with, this is a completely unknown topic to me. I'm not even sure that I should ask this question on this site from all the Stack Exchange sites. But we are creating small unmanned aircraft. And I want to develop a piloting system for him. I use ros with the rosplane package as a platform for this project. In rosplane, the flight over control points has already been implemented, which is quite convenient. But we are developing this project to participate in a competition where we must pursue other planes and "shoot them" down. A **stable** camera is installed on the plane (this is the condition of a competition that is stable) and rotates ahead.
[image]

Something similar is in the arcade flight simulators where the player directs the plane with the mouse. I can’t figure out how to make the ailerons in a real plane (And other details of the plane) move so that the plane turns to our target along this blue arrow.
Perhaps there is some kind of literature or article about it, but I can’t find it because I don’t know the topic and don’t know how to search.

Answer (score 0):

you can use your forward-facing camera to determine the setpoints you send to the controller by calculating the position of the aircraft It's are chasing, relative to the center of forward moving axis. and with the scale of detected aircraft based on your total size of the camera frame, u can determine if you are getting closer or farther.

Personally, I haven't used RosPlane Since there are better flightcontrollers such as [PX4 Autopilot](https://github.com/PX4/Firmware) or [Ardupilot](https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot) to use for Vision Controlling the Drone.